# Visualforce Table - Iterate Over Two Different Objects with Same Column Headers?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-datatable, pageblocktable, datatable

I need to create a data table that contains Task and Opportunity data, but puts them together in the same table that uses days of the week for column headers. Example below - I've never seen a way to iterate over two different objects in the same table, anyone done this before? Is there a way to create two PageBlockTables but have them appear right above/below each other to create the same effect?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, things like apex:dataTable and apex:panelGrid won't generate this kind of table for you. You need to do it yourself.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <apex:repeat items="{!userdata}" var="data">
      <tr><td colspan="6">Tasks for {!data.name}</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td># of Tasks</td>
        <td>{!data.mondayTasks}</td>
        <td>{!data.tuesdayTasks}</td>
        <td>{!data.wednesdayTasks}</td>
        <td>{!data.thursdayTasks}</td>
        <td>{!data.fridayTasks}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="6">Accounts for {!data.name}</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td># of Tasks</td>
        <td>{!data.mondayAccounts}</td>
        <td>{!data.tuesdayAccounts}</td>
        <td>{!data.wednesdayAccounts}</td>
        <td>{!data.thursdayAccounts}</td>
        <td>{!data.fridayAccounts}</td>
      </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This also means you'll need a wrapper object, and some maps to associate all the data together. The above code should give you a starting point, you just need the Apex from here.